# XML/SOAP attributes for a complextype in kSOAP

Tags: xml, android, soap, ksoap, complextype

I'm trying to parse a SOAP response that contains nested `ComplexType`s using the kSOAP library on Android 2.1.

```
<event att1="value1" att2="value2" att3="value3"> 
   <tag2> ... </tag2>
   <tag3> ... </tag3>
</event>
```

I've implemented my own class `Event` that implements `org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable` to parse this response.

It is not clear to me if and how I can parse/deserialize the attributes (`att1`, `att2` and `att3`) of the `event` node. Is it even possible with the current kSOAP implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, reading attributes is not possible with the kSOAP library. That's why I'd rather not use it.

EDIT: after searching on the web for a bit I found out that there seems to be a patch out which makes it able to read attributes. I think you can download it here but I'm not sure if it's the right one: [Link to Download](http://www.sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1473145&group_id=158028&atid=806189)

But apperently these guys somewhat managed to get it to work:

([last few posts are discussing it](http://www.supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/KSOAP-not-getting-full-XML/td-p/140388/page/2)).

Hope this helps. Let me know if you figured it out.

ANOTHER EDIT:
Try this link. It definitely works in reading attributes with kSOAP:

[This Post](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/05/attribute-support-for-ksoap2-on-android/)

Answer (score 2):

I am the author os the attribute patch and now the project maintainer of ksaop2-android. http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Attribute parsing definitely works with the code from my project version 2.5.1 and the latest 2.5.2. I am using it in an application that is live in Android market without problems.

See the wiki page on how to go about using it:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse

and also see some of the links in the wiki links page to see how to get marshalling to work.

Comment: Hi ManFred, 
The fixed version is able to parse the attribute in response object. Can you please help me in how can I add attributes in request object? I already tried with addAttribute method but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: ask as a separate question what you did and the problem you encounter either on stackoverflow and post to the mailing list or ask on the mailinglist